# Magento 2 XML for Bundled Products only

Tags: magento2, product, bundled-product

The code below works for my product pages. However, I cannot find what to wrap it in so it only renders on "bundled" product pages. Please Help.

```
<move element="product.info.description" destination="product.info.main" after="product.info.price" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Write below xml code into your theme Magneto_Bundle module's layout folder **catalog_product_view_type_bundle.xml** file.

**app/design/frontend/{Packagename}/{themename}/Magento_Bundle/layout/catalog_product_view_type_bundle.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
       <move element="product.info.description" destination="product.info.main" after="product.info.price" />
    </body>
</page>
```

Clear cache.
**Above code is working only in bundle product page.**

Comment: Is there another way to word this? It doesn't render for me. Is there a way to instantiate it if it wasn't there first?